# Applying 1D cosine taper to 3D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, windowing

I have a time series dataset which I have windowed into n segments. My data now has dimensions (n, t, x, y). I wish to apply a cosine taper with dimension (t,) to each segment, but I obviously cannot multiply an array of dimension (t,) to an array of dimension (t, x, y).

Can someone provide me with a way to do this?

Comment: Provide sample data and expected output please to ensure that problem can be reproduced by readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can multiply them using NumPy [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

In this case just reshape your cosine window and multiply something like

```
# data set with shape (n, t, x, y), window has shape (t,)
tapered_data = data * window.reshape(1, t, 1, 1)
```

Comment: Thank you David! this does exactly what I was looking for.